# How to deal with long-lived feature branch?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch

I am working on a long-lived feature branch. Unfortunately, I cannot dedicate all my time to this feature branch, and have to switch back and forth between the main trunk for regular day-to-day coding, and feature branch when I have free time.

I am trying to merge the trunk into the feature branch in order to keep the feature branch up to date, but am getting a lot of conflicts, and I just realized why:

After resolving a conflict, I commit the fixed file to the Branch, however the Trunk version of the file does NOT changes. It will ALWAYS have merge conflicts with the branch file, even after the conflict is resolved. For example, see the conflict below:

[image: First Conflict]

I then fix this conflict by making changes to the Branch version of the file, and then commit it to the Branch. The Branch now looks like this:

[image: Branch after fixing conflict]

Now, if I do another merge, I will still get a conflict at line 3 because the Trunk version of the file never changed:

[image: Still a conflict exists since Trunk version of the file was never changed]

**Question**: How do you deal with long-lived branches, in terms of merging and dealing with conflicts?

Comment: Why do you say the last case (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aks0W.png) will generate a conflict? There is just one extra line in "Branch", merging should not be problematic.

Comment: What Subversion client and server version do you use? What FSFS repository filesystem format does your repository have? Is it format 3 or higher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of SVN/TortoiseSVN you're using?

Do you commit **mergeinfo** changes when you merge from the Trunk to the Branch?

As far as I can tell, there should be no conflicts if you are using modern version of SVN (1.10.x or newer) and if you are commiting mergeinfo changes properly.

> The `svn:mergeinfo` property is automatically maintained by Subversion
>   whenever you run svn merge. Its value **indicates which changes made to
>   a given path have been replicated into the directory in question**.

Check the [Mergeinfo and Previews](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo) chapter of the [svnbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/) for further details.

Comment: It is possible that their repository has FSFS format version 2 or 1 and has to be upgraded. Merge tracking / `svn:mergeinfo` was implemented in SVN 1.5 with FSFS format 3. SVN 1.5 was released more than 10 years ago. However, you can still find SVN 1.4 servers because admins did not bother with upgrading them - SVN just works. Upgrading to SVN 1.10.x is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. We are running SVN 1.11. I'm not sure why, but when I would try to do a merge from trunk to branch for the first time, I would get the conflict, fix the conflict, commit the fixed version into the branch (since the merge happens to the working copy). I then would do another merge, and the same conflict that I just fixed would appear again.

Comment: We also use AnkhSVN, a plug-in for Visual Studio, that integrates with the SVN. After the merge, I would fix all conflicts, and commit all merged changes that would appear in the "Pending Changes" tab in the AnkhSVN plug-in. However, I was totally forgetting to commit items that did not appear in that tab (for whatever reason). I then did a commit from the root level, which showed me ALL merged files, and this seems to have solved the problem.